# Should we use Redux pattern in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

Hi i am new in react native development.I have learn a lot stuff of react native but right now i want to know about Redux pattern. I have little bit knowledge of Redux but my question is should we use Redux in react native app if yes then how much this pattern is effective. Because the mobile app have many screen than react.js one page site.

Comment: I recommend using redux, along with `redux-saga` and use `reselect`, too. Don't build a slice of state for every component, but rather structure your app simply, using memoized selectors to afford you caching and complex calculations.

Comment: I think it's a good paradigm to use overall for react native development, especially as the app grows larger and more complex, redux can be a god send later.